# Mesh streching when rotating bone

Tags: modeling, armature

I have a stickfigure that I made and I want to rig. Most of the thing is working fine but the arms and legs are streching very weirdly. I want to make it in a way that, for example, if I rotate the elbow, the scale of the mesh wont change just the rotation of the mesh. I also want to be able to rotate each cylinder individually in its local location, regardless of the global location. So currently I am looking to make the normal mesh work and then adding this on top somehow. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is how it is in Rest: [image]
Here is with some rotation: [image]

I read some of the other posts but after attempting the solutions, I keep getting the same issue.
The file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8j4y8iofyul67z/stickfigure.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've scaled the armature in *Object* mode, you need to apply the scale in *Object* mode and it will work correctly (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

About your deformation problem: After parenting *With Automatic Weight* you need to give some corrections in *Weight Paint* mode:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue with the streching. Do you also know how to fix this scaling issue in the elbow? [picture](https://imgur.com/a/sb39X3O)

I guess that can be fixed with the vertex weights. Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's a problem of rigging, you need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode after parent with automatic weight